# Finding the limit of a particular function

Tags: limits

Can not understand the following limit in a past paper.

$$\dfrac{1}{[n(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)]}\rightarrow 1$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this notation. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(1 +\frac1n+\frac{(\frac1n)^2}{2!}+\dots-1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\frac1n}{2!}+\dots} = 1
$$
using Taylor expansion for exponential function
$$
e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $e^{\frac 1 n} - 1 \operatorname*{=}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: $O((\frac1n)^2)$

Comment: That's also true, but it doesn't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the expansion of $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ..$ and simplify the denominator.